# Visual Studio Setup Project User Desktop Shortcut icon doesn't work... why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, icons, setup-project

I developed a VS Setup Project with many Projects Output. I added 3 desktop shortcuts to my project outputs and I attached the .exe icon to the shortcut. After run the setup, I can see only one icon and the other 2 icons are the application default icon as showed in my [desktop shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlW2j.png).

The only one difference to the icons are the size: the first one correctly showed is 128x128, the other 2 are 512x512 but if I open the Debug folder in the App Project the icon look very well.
Does VS Setup project have a limitation for icons??

Comment: It is recommended that you check your icon file. I did not find any relevant documents that require icon resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a demo using Visual Studio Installer Project.

I used two icons, one 128x128 and one 669x512. Both can be displayed correctly.

One of the icons I used had an error during the test and couldn't run. (The reason for my error is that there is an error in the icon file, so it cannot be displayed correctly. It is recommended that you check your icon file)

[image]

Edit:The problem was windows doesn't refresh immediately the folder icon miniatures... Op have to to copy and paste the exe file in a new folder and icon displays correctly!

Comment: The problem was windows doesn't refresh immediately the folder icon miniatures... I have to to copy and paste the exe file in a new folder and icon displays correctly!

Comment: @LucaPannozzo I have updated my answer. You could mark it as the answer. So, it would help the person who has the same issue.